# BlocProvider in flutter in error Navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, state-management

I'm making an app in flutter and in the main, when I navigate with a button its shows an error:

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

1.You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
To fix, perform a hot-restart.

2.The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
other routes will not be able to access that provider.

3.You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

Make sure that BlocBuilder<AppBloc, AppState> is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately

```
Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.web,
      );
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AppBloc(),
          child: MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
            ],
            child: const MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: WelcomeScreen(),
              title: "Safe Road",
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

but for some reasón its still the same error, any Idea what can I do?

```
class AppBloc extends Bloc<AppEvent, AppState> {
  AppBloc()
      : super(const AppStateLoggedOut(isLoading: true, succesful: false)) {
    on<AppEventLogIn>((event, emit) async {
      emit(const AppStateLoggedOut(isLoading: true, succesful: false));
      try {
        await Auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: event.email, password: event.password);
        emit(const AppStateLoggedIn(isLoading: false, succesful: true));
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print(e);
        authErrorLogin = e.toString();
        emit(const AppStateLoggedIn(isLoading: false, succesful: true));
      }
    });
    on<AppEventLogOut>((event, emit) async {
      emit(const AppStateLoggedOut(isLoading: true, succesful: false));
      try {
        await Auth().signOut();
        emit(const AppStateLoggedOut(isLoading: false, succesful: true));
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {}
    });
    on<AppEventRegister>((event, emit) async {
      emit(const AppStateLoggedOut(isLoading: true, succesful: false));
      try {
        await Auth().createUserWithEmaildAndPassword(
            email: event.email, password: event.password);
        emit(const AppStateLoggedIn(isLoading: false, succesful: true));
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print(e);
        authErrorLogin = e.toString();
        emit(const AppStateLoggedIn(isLoading: false, succesful: true));
      }
    });
    on<AppEventResetPassword>((event, emit) async {
      emit(const AppStateLoggedOut(isLoading: true, succesful: false));
      try {
        await Auth().sendResetPasswordEmail(email: event.email);
        emit(const AppStateLoggedIn(isLoading: false, succesful: true));
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        print(e);
        authErrorLogin = e.toString();
        emit(const AppStateLoggedOut(isLoading: false, succesful: false));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This is the class of AppBloc, the class is in the provider and when it initializate to the email view its fine, but when get into the password view shows the same error: This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider

All this with the BLoC Pattern

This is the view of the password

```
class _PasswordViewState extends State<PasswordView> {
  bool visiblePassword = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, bottom: 25),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Insert a password',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Insert a password to create your account',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.password,
                      color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 15,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 250,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: passwordController,
                        obscureText: visiblePassword,
                        autofocus: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    visiblePassword = !visiblePassword;
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.remove_red_eye,
                                  color: visiblePassword
                                      ? Colors.grey.shade500
                                      : Colors.blue,
                                )),
                            focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                            hintText: 'Contraseña',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500))),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            BlocBuilder<AppBloc, AppState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: state.isLoading
                        ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                        : ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 250,
                              height: 50,
                              child: MaterialButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  context.read<AppBloc>().add(AppEventRegister(
                                      email: emailController.text,
                                      password: passwordController.text));
                                  Navigator.of(context)
                                      .popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                                },
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                child: const Text('Confirm'),
                              ), ),), ),); },)],),),);}}
```

Comment: can you include your blocBuilder on widget tree

Comment: And I think you can include `AppBloc` inside MultiProvider

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are facing this because you are using `BlocProvider` of `AppBloc` as ancestor of the `MultiBlocProvider`

To solve this issue, try to provide `AppBloc` in the `BlocProvider`.Like:

```
MultiProvider(
            providers: [
             BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
               create: (BuildContext context) => AuthBloc(), //  Use it here
             ),  
              ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
            ],
            child: const MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: WelcomeScreen(),
              title: "Safe Road",
            ),
          ),
```

And remove the wrapper of `BlocProvider` on `MultiBlocProvider`.

Comment: Hey bro, I got another Issue, I'm making the project with the BLoC Pattern, and the AppBloc that makes the original error it's shows again when I try to put the view of the password. When you help me was for the view of the Email, but in the password shows the error, let me put the code